# Why do I get a different file content when I'm opening it with different Emacs versions on Windows7

Tags: find-file

I'm opening the very same file with Emacs-24.5 and with Emacs-23.1.  But the latter shows me what seems to be an older version of this file!  Might this be a bug of in Emacs-23.1?

I updated the question with images showing the file (opened with `C-x C-f`) content and the respective output of `(buffer-file-name)`

[image: The image show that there are different contents for the same file]

[image: buffer-file-name]

Comment: Check the value of `buffer-file-name` for each file and see if one has slightly different name -- e.g., with a tilde or something.  `M-x describe-variable RET buffer-file-name RET`.

Comment: What @lawlist said. Probably two different files, and pilot error.

Comment: I updated my question please have a look.

Comment: Dieter.Wilhelm: That's a picture of what you described, but doesn't really help. Show us the `buffer-file-name` values for each one (as lawlist suggested). You might also tell us *exactly* how you're opening the file in each one?

Comment: @phils: Sorry forgot, added now an image with the output of the command.

Comment: Just throwing in a few ideas : you could check `(verify-visited-file-modtime)`. You could also look at the file in dired to check its attributes/last modification time, or simply `(file-attributes buffer-file-name)` but it's less readable. Might also want to check `(file-truename buffer-file-name)` just in case.

Comment: @YoungFrog: file-truname yields the same name for both Emacsen.

Comment: @YoungFrog: But looking in dired shows me with Emacs-23 as the owner my user name but with Emacs-24.5 Administrator as owner (I've got open user rights)!

Comment: @Dieter.Wilhelm Well, this looks like very advanced technology. I give up, sorry !